# how to represent metadata in a data warehouse

Tags: ssas, azure-data-catalog

I am working on to create a data warehouse. I have made a database which will be the data warehouse and will consist of dimension and fact tables. I know that other than dimension and fact table a data warehouse should also consist of a meta data, now my question is what should be the structure of metadata and all the information it should have?

Comment: Are you talking about a data dictionary defining the meaning of each table and column? Or are you talking about tables that define lineage like which ETL package last touched this row and when?

Comment: @GregGalloway, I am talking about a data dictionary defining the meaning of each table and column in the data warehouse, so that an external can have an idea about what information is available in which table. Further on the second peace about defining lineage, if you can let me know more about that also I will be very much thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about having Azure Data Catalog capture the table and column names and let developers and business users collaborate on the definitions in a UI? This would be a great data dictionary. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-catalog/

Or if you want to roll your own with extended properties you might do the following:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1637/script-to-build-a-sql-server-data-dictionary-and-report-with-microsoft-excel/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this can be an option when we move to Azure as currently I don't have access to Azure environment, but before Azure How it used to be managed that is what I want to know, I want more information on how to manage than what to manage, If you can provide me some info or some link so that I know that what should be the structure of data dictionary which is to be prepared to represent metadata.

Comment: Updated answer to mention rolling your own

Comment: I have tried both the options you suggested above. I have now access to azure, and discovering Azure Data Catalog. This is awesome and hopefully will solve much more than what I need. This is much more than a data dictionary.